# How to install and activate NVIDIA card on ASUS ROG GL752VW

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu/Linux. I have just installed it 3 days ago!

I would greatly appreciate some help with a graphical problem.

The thing that started this process was something that bugged me to no end: my wallpaper was showing grossly visible gradient banding. If anybody can suggest a way for me to properly show what I see on my monitor, I would gladly comply. I imagine just posting a screenshot here is besides the point and a photograph of the screen doesn’t really show the extent of the effect, in my opinion. Because of this visual problem, I thought there must be something I have to do about my dedicated graphics card.

I do not actually know how a device with an integrated graphical card and a dedicated one works, let alone graphical cards in general. I have tried by myself to *install my NVIDIA GeForce GTX960M card on my current notebook (ASUS ROG GL752VW), but to no avail*. ***I would love to read and understand terms like Nouveau, Wayland, NVIDIA proprietary drivers, X11 and so on (I have just seen this thrown around, that is I made a "word soup" there)***. I would like a recommended source for this subject that hopefully is noob-friendly.

The steps I have undergone so far:

1. While being logged in on just "Ubuntu" (not "Ubuntu in Wayland", as I've found out later), I've checked with `lspci -v` which components Ubuntu can recognize on my system and the only *VGA adapter* is the Intel card. The NVIDIA card was showing up only as a *3D Controller*. Without properly understanding what these meant, I thought that I needed to install the NVIDIA proprietary driver so it can use the GTX960M as a VGA controller too.
2. I checked which version of the NVIDIA proprietary is recommended with `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`.
3. *nvidia-driver-390* was the recommended one so I proceeded to install it without having the PPA.
4. After installing I checked the *Additional Drivers* section of *Software and Updates* and the *nvidia-driver-390* was checked as being used.
5. Thinking everything was ok, I tried `nvidia-settings` in the terminal and got an error saying the driver is not loaded and some other text (please excuse my short memory).
6. I've started reading how to try to solve this and found out you can log in to something called "Ubuntu in Wayland", again not understanding what this was. Thus, I log in like this.
7. I've found that there is a PPA with updated drivers and I add it to my repositories.
8. I run a `sudo apt-get update` and after that a `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
9. The command updated the driver to *nvidia-driver-396*
10. I check nvidia-settings again. The error that I get now is:
        ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system.
11. Out of curiosity, I check `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` again and now *nvidia-driver-396* is the one that has the recommended flag.
12. Re-did steps 10-11 while being logged on “Ubuntu” with the same results.
13. Having a brief encounter with Node.js problems, I used `sudo apt-get autoremove` and a bunch of dependencies of both version 390 and 396 show up.
14. I went back to *Software and Updates* > *Additional Drivers* and re-checked “Use Nouve display driver…”

As a last question, is it even possible to force Ubuntu to always use the dedicated card for everything? Like the Desktop and so on? I know this is not possible on Windows, where I could enable the NVIDIA card only for games and specific apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently on Nvidia Optimus (Intel's iGPU controls the laptop display, but some programs can be routed through the Nvidia GPU), which is very problematic with Nvidia drivers, no Nvidia driver on Linux can give you the same Optimus behaviour as on Microsoft Windows.
You could use Prime to completely switch GPUs when having an Optimus setup (I never tried that), or you could just deactive one of your GPUs in the BIOS settings which would save you from all the Nvidia Optimus troubles.